# multiple ajax calls is causing mixed datasets

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cordova, jquery-mobile

I've been developing a phonegap application which uses jQuery Mobile for it's main structure.

When the site/app runs, it executes a number of ajax calls to get the latest data to the app. For example, a list of items is gathered for the homepage, whilst other lists of other items are gathered for other pages.

What I am finding is that every now and then there is a mixup in data.

**As a random (but applicable) example:**

*Query 1* - get names and photos of people

*Query 2* - get names and photos of cities/locations

In each of the ajax calls, instead of using (data, status) I have renamed the data object to a unique identifier hoping this would resolve the issue.

Then, on my $.each function I have ensured that the iterator has a different name too, so instead of (i, item) it might be (i, personitem) and (i, cityitem)

**The Issue**

Despite my best attempts to get this data to not have any possibility of crossover, I'm finding that (to keep with the current example) - photos of people will show up on the cities page, and photos of cities will show up on the users page.

This is also an intermittent issue. Sometimes it won't happen at all, other times it will happen a lot or only a little bit.

I hope I have explained myself clearly. Thank you in advanced to anyone willing to help! I'm all out of ideas :-(

==================

**UPDATE**

My main question is if anyone knows what might cause data-mixups in such queries.

My queries all look like this:

```
$.ajax({
           url: 'get_cities.php?country='+country,
           dataType: 'jsonp',
           jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
           timeout: 5000,
           success: function(citydata, status){
           if(citydata.length == 0){
                $('#somediv').append('no data to show');
           }
           $.each(citydata, function(i,cityitem){
                var content = '<img src="'+cityitem.image+'" />'
                             +'<p>'+cityitem.name+'</p>';

                $('#somediv').append(content);
          }
});
```

Comment: You need to show your code - we can't guess what the issue is

Comment: I've added an update with an actual query I use. All my ajax requests are more or less the same format. My question is simple, are you aware of anything that might cause multiple ajax requests to cross data with each other?

Comment: Just to confirm, you are using the correct url for the different ajax calls, right?

Comment: Also, are you using different names for your jasonp callback?

Comment: Yep 100%. Each call is very different to the other. And probably 4 out of 5 times this issue doesn't happen. Usually every fourth or fifth reload it will randomly start mixing information. Note that in my implementation there are a good dozen ajax calls that run on app-load. But they all reference the correct url, correct parameters, and have unique object names and iterators

Comment: @mason81 are you referring to jsonp: 'jsoncallback' ?  how would one go about setting a custom jsonp callback name?

Comment: @WilliamCross Yes, I am referring to `jsonp: 'jsoncallback'`, but I am not certain that is the cause of your problem, only mentioning it may be. Take a look at: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/. Specifically look at the #data-types section, there is a paragraph that explains how jsonp works. You may not be using the callback correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this point I believe @mason81 was correct with his suggestion.

I removed all of the:

```
jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
```

in my code, and then updated my PHP files to use

```
echo $_GET['callback'] . '(' . json_encode($records) . ');';
```

instead of

```
echo $_GET['jsoncallback'] . '(' . json_encode($records) . ');';
```

I originally also placed &callback=? into my URL's but from reading the jQuery Ajax documentation it should automatically assign a random unique callback to each call as long as you are using dataType: jsonp without manually specifying a callback parameter.

If this fails I'll still consider this the correct answer, I'll probably just have to go through and either assign unique callback parameters to each request or ammend my URL's with &callback=? as mentioned above.

Thanks everyone for their input!

Comment: you don't need to use jsonp

Comment: issue didn't end up being with the json requests at all! ha! my bad.. All the same though I found the feedback incredibly helpful, thanks to the community! :-)